# How can I load a string from DB to url_for() flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I'm building an online store with flask and save the image name in a DB but I tried loading the name to the `url_for(filename='')` like in the code below but it's not loading the name and it's giving an error `expected token ',' got 'string'`.

My code:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=f'img/Shop-img/{product.image_name}.png') }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
```

What's stored inside `product.image_name`:

[image: product.image_name]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by using `.format(product.image_name)` like this:

New code:

`<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/Shop-img/{}'.format(product.image_name)) }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">`